# how to bring back stashed file which is not committed in git?

Tags: git

I'm trying to find out which branch I have stashed my recent 5 hours work.
I typed stash by mistake and all my changes gone!

By accident I typed:

```
git stash
```

This is what I saw[image]:

Then I checked my branch:

[image]

Then I tried to bring back my stash. I checkout to my branch and typed

```
git stash pop
```

And now I get this:

```
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   ******************/UIViewController+Keyboard.h
    new file:   ******************/UIViewController+Keyboard.m

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   ******************.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
    modified:   ******************/CTAuthenticateUserViewController.m

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    ******************/Base.lproj/Bernard copy.storyboard
    ******************/Base.lproj/Bernard.storyboard
    ******************/Keyboard.h
```

This is what I guess is right:

```
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
```

This means delete all my stashed files by upstaging them!

```
use "git add <file>..."
```

This will replace current files with stashed files?!

```
"git checkout -- <file>...
```

stashed changes goes to bin and last commit become head

```
 "git add <file>..."
```

This will add these file to current branch, which comes from stash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `git stash pop` applies your stashed changes to the currently checked out worktree.
If the command did not give any errors like "conflicts arised" or similar, git was able to apply the changes and delete the stash-commit from the stash stack.
After `stash apply` or `stash pop` is finished, it does a `git status` so that you see the current state of your worktree.
Stashing also preserves what you added to the index and what you just had modfied without adding to the index.
So you should have all your work back now and can continue as you like.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was wondering what those hint in git status means.

Comment: By the way I just realized all vanished files are back

Comment: Well, it has nothing to do with stashing, it is just normal `git status` output that hints on what commands you could use on the specific files to achieve some typical goals.